# StackOverFlowException after login to JSP login form

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

I'm try to open form login.jsp but getting `javax.servlet.ServletException`

> The server side component of the HTTP Monitor has detected a `java.lang.StackOverflowError`.
>   This happens when there is an infinite loop in the web module.
>   Correct the cause of the infinite loop before running the web module again

#### LoginController code :

```
public class LoginController extends HttpServlet {

public LoginController()
{
    sandiBank = "null";
    session = null;
    mUserDao = new MUserDao();
    sandiBIDao = new SandiBIDao();
    cabangDao = new CabangDao();
    parameterDao = new ParameterDao();
    mAccesDao = new MAccesDao();
}

@Override
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest httpservletrequest, HttpServletResponse httpservletresponse)
    throws ServletException, IOException
{
    httpservletrequest.getRequestDispatcher("./login.jsp").forward(httpservletrequest, httpservletresponse);
}

@Override
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
    throws ServletException, IOException
{
    String user = request.getParameter("user");
    String pass = request.getParameter("pass");
    MUser mUser = mUserDao.getMUser(user);
    if(!mUser.isCheck())
    {
        RequestDispatcher dispatcher = request.getRequestDispatcher("login.jsp");
        dispatcher.forward(request, response);
    } else
    {
        Cabang cabang = cabangDao.getSandiBank(mUser.getKdCab());
        if(cabang.getSandiBank() != null)
            sandiBank = cabang.getSandiBank();
        RequestDispatcher dispatcher = request.getRequestDispatcher("home.jsp");
        session = request.getSession(true);
        session.setAttribute("userid", user);
        session.setAttribute("passwd", pass);
        String userid = (String)session.getAttribute("userid");
        session.setAttribute("kdcaba", mUser.getKdCab());
        session.setAttribute("sndbnk", sandiBank);
        System.out.println(session.getAttribute("sndbnk"));
        session.setAttribute("sandikd_bank", parameterDao.getSandiBank());
        session.setMaxInactiveInterval(3600);
        request.setAttribute("sandiBI", sandiBIDao.getSandiBI());
        request.setAttribute("mAccesses", mAccesDao.getmAccesses(userid));
        dispatcher.forward(request, response);
    }
}

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
private MUserDao mUserDao;
private SandiBIDao sandiBIDao;
private MAccesDao mAccesDao;
private CabangDao cabangDao;
private ParameterDao parameterDao;
private String sandiBank;
private HttpSession session;
}
```

Comment: you should add a stacktrace

Comment: It's right time to learn how to debug in java. There is definitely a code which is been called recursively and blows up the stack with local variables

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This usually means that you have a recursive call in your code.

A recursion is simply a method that calls itself, causing the stack to overflow and throw the StackoverFlow exception.

check  flow of your  code where method call itself

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
httpservletrequest.getRequestDispatcher("./login.jsp").forward(httpservletrequest, httpservletresponse);
```

To

```
httpservletrequest.getRequestDispatcher("/login.jsp").forward(httpservletrequest, httpservletresponse);
```